# Create custom Tensorflow dataset .tiff files

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, training-data, generative-adversarial-network, custom-data-type

I am new on **Tensorflow**, and I would like to create a custom dataset for using ESRGAN next.

The issues I meet are :

- I have `(low_resolution, high_resolution)` images as couple of data
- All my images are `.tiff` files
- I want to create batches of size `8` with this dataset, to further use the `train_step(self, batch)` function of **Tensorflow**: to be clearer, I want it to iter automatically at each epoch on every batch of 8

Ideally, I would like it to be made in the same way as the `tensorflow_datasets` module (`tfds`)

How can I instantiate a classe / create a class to do so ?

Thanks for your help